# XML format error using ASIS3request Amazon S3

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

I am using ASIS3request to upload a photo from iPhone to Amazon S3
service.

Basically I followed the instructions in the documentation.

However I get the following error:

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
> our published schema.

This is my code:

```
   ASIS3Request *request = [ASIS3Request PUTRequestForFile:uniquePath withBucket:@"catcontest" path:@""];
   [request setSecretAccessKey:@"..."];
   [request setAccessKey:@"....."];

   [request start];
    if ([request error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code sample is incomplete or censored, but the section `path:@""` looks like it should have something in between the quotes, possibly a path to an xml file?

A non-validating XML error would be consistent with a missing xml file.

(this is just a guess, I know nothing about ASIS3request!)